# Find all links inside a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My html page has:

```
...
<table class="t1" ..>
<tr><td> ... <a href="">...</a> ... <a href="">..</a>
</table>

...
```

I have:

```
html = BeautifulSoup(page)

links = html.findAll('a', ?????????)
```

How can I find all links that are inside this table?

Comment: Have you looked into Python HTML Parsers?

Comment: @Nick - That would be what BeautifulSoup is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the table ([by class](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Searching%20by%20CSS%20class) in this case), then find all the links within it.

```
html = BeautifulSoup(page)
table = html.find('table', 't1')
links = table.findAll('a')
```

Comment: `links` will be a list of `Tag` objects: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20attributes%20of%20Tags

Answer (score 1):

More efficient than a raw find, use `SoupStrainer`:

```
html  = BeautifulSoup(page, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('table', 't1' ) )
links = html.findAll('a')
```

See also, the [Search by Class documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Searching%20by%20CSS%20class).

Answer (score 0):

This should return a list of links in the page

```
html = BeautifulSoup(page)
links = html.findAll('a')
```

Comment: i don't want all the links on the page, only the links inside the table with class=t1